# Django Rest Framework: field name 'likes' is not valid for model 'userPost' improperlyConfigured

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my Django Rest Framework api I am attempting to add a property to my model UserPosts that returns all likes for said post. Despite my best efforts I keep running into this error. Here is my post model below:

```
class UserPosts(models.Model):
    userProfile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=240)

    @property
    def get_likes(self):
        from liked.models import Like
        return Like(post=self)
```

and here is my like model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    post = models.ForeignKey(UserPosts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

and lastly the post serializer:

```
class postSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserPosts
        fields = ('userProfile', 'image', 'caption', 'likes')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Replace `likes`, with `like_set` in the `postSerializer` (and you better fix that naming style).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you so much. I don't have enough rep to upvote you or I would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least three ways. First as @WillemVanOnsem said, by the [many_to_one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) change the `likes` to `like_set`

```
class postSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserPosts
        fields = ('userProfile', 'image', 'caption', 'like_set')
        #                                             ^^^^^
```

Second rename your model's property to `likes` and fix the queryset inside it

```
class UserPosts(models.Model):
    userProfile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=240)

    @property
    def likes(self):
    #   ^^^^^
        from liked.models import Like
        return Like.objects.filter(post=self).values() or []
        # solution you try ^^^^^^^
        return self.like_set.values() or []
        # more django way
```

And Third, the most simple and elegant way for me, is to remove your `get_likes` and add the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to the `post` `ForeignKey`:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    post = models.ForeignKey(UserPosts, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    liked_at = models.DateTimeField()
```